# Add new file to existing 7z archive, but place it in a subfolder

Tags: 7zip

I have 7z archive that looks like this

```
archive.7z
/
 -Folder1
   file1
 -Folder2
   file2
```

I know that I can add file3 to the root by

`7za.exe a archive.7z file3`

But I want to add file3 in Folder2. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/238399/how-to-specify-relative-path-in-7-zip-command-line/1097301

You can create directory structure similar to archive one and compress it with required file inside

Comment: FYI - This should be a comment, not an answer. Also, it's been closed at this point, marked as a general computing question (which would then be marked as a duplicate if reposted or migrated there).

Comment: Yep this worked fine